# How to disconnect socket.io on page change

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I want to disconnect socket when i change a page on my website, to have readings only for the specific sensor I am targeting, My code for all sockets looks roughly the same, here is the one for temperature sensors(ds18b20).

For example:
When I change from Temperature Page to Humidity Page, I want tempsocket to close/disconnect and humidity socket to open and vice versa.(each sensor has its own javascript)

```
var value;  //Temperature sensor 1 values
var value2; //Temperature sensor 2 values

createGraph(); //Call the functions for it to make a clean graph at the start.

var values = []; //create an Array of values from Temperature sensor 1
var values2 = []; //create an Array of values from Temperature sensor 2

var times = []; //create an Array of times

var text = 'txtArea'; //enter the name of the text field

var chartColors = {
    red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
    yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    grey: 'rgb(231,233,237)'
};
//---------------------Temperature1 + 2 ----------------------------------------
var tempsocket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

tempsocket.on('connect', function (){
    tempsocket.on('mqtt', function (msg){

  var elmarr=msg.topic.split("/");
  var elm=elmarr[3];

  if( elmarr.indexOf('Temp1') >= 0){//Temperature1 queue
    var sendData = "Internal: " + msg.payload;
    printText(text,elm,sendData); //Publish data to the textArea
    var value = (parseFloat(msg.payload)); //convert the string to float
    values.push(value); //Pass the temperature reading into the array
  };

  if( elmarr.indexOf('Temp2') >= 0){//Temperature2 queue
    var sendData2 = "External: " + msg.payload;
    printText(text,elm,sendData2); //Publish data to the textArea
    var value2 = (parseFloat(msg.payload)); //convert the string to float
    values2.push(value2); //Pass the temperature reading into the array
  };

  var d = new Date();//Get Date/Time for the times array
  var n = d.getHours()+ ":" + d.getMinutes()+ ":" + d.getSeconds();
  times.push(n);

    if(values.length > 6)//Delete the first value in the Temperature Array
    {
      values.splice(0, 1);
    }

    if(values2.length > 6)//Delete the first value in the Temperature Array
    {
      values2.splice(0, 1);
    }

    if(times.length > 6)//Delete the first value in the Time Array
    {
      times.splice(0, 1);
    }

  createGraph(values, values2, times);

});//Subscribe to the queue
     tempsocket.emit('subscribe',{topic:'SmartHive/Temperature/#'});
});
//-----------------------Print to Text Area-------------------------------------
function printText(chatID,ValueElm,PayloadValue){
  $('#'+chatID).append("\n" + PayloadValue);
  $('#'+chatID).scrollTop($('#'+chatID)[0].scrollHeight);
  $('#'.concat(ValueElm)).html(PayloadValue);
};
 //-----------------------Line Graph---------------------------------------------
//Function to create the line graph
function createGraph(dataValues, dataValues2, dataTimes){
  var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
  labels: dataTimes,//Passing the array to be the labels
  datasets: [{
      label: 'Internal Temperature',
      data: dataValues,//Passing the array to be the data set
    borderColor: "#3e95cd",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(62, 149, 205, 0.4)",
    // backgroundColor: chartColors.red,
    // borderColor: chartColors.red,
    fill: true
    },
  {
      label: 'External Temperature',
      data: dataValues2,//Passing the array to be the data set
    borderColor: "#ff00e5",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 229, 0.4)",
    // backgroundColor: chartColors.blue,
    // borderColor: chartColors.blue,
    fill: true
    }
    ]
  },
  options: {
  responsive: true,
  // title: {
  //   display: true,
  //   text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
  // },
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'label',
  },
  hover: {
    mode: 'nearest',
    intersect: true
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Time'
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Temperature'
      }
  }]
    }
  }
}
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
  new Chart(ctx, options);
};
```

Edit: Solution, Instead of closing the socket that gave me problems, I just started calling everything inside of the if statement, now the Chart works better and I don't get anything weird going on.

```
if(elmarr.indexOf('Temperature') >= 0){

  if( elmarr.indexOf('Temp1') >= 0){//Temperature1 queue
    var value = (parseFloat(msg.payload)); //convert the string to float
    values.push(value); //Pass the temperature reading into the array
  };

  if( elmarr.indexOf('Temp2') >= 0){//Temperature2 queue
    var value2 = (parseFloat(msg.payload)); //convert the string to float
    values2.push(value2); //Pass the temperature reading into the array
    var d = new Date();//Get Date/Time for the times array
    var n = d.getHours()+ ":" + d.getMinutes()+ ":" + d.getSeconds();
    times.push(n);
    if(times.length > values.length || times.length > values2.length){
        EmptyArrays(values, values2, times);
    }else{
        createGraph(values, values2, times);
    };
  };

  if(values.length > 6)//Delete the first value in the Temperature Array
  {
    values.splice(0, 1);
  }

  if(values2.length > 6)//Delete the first value in the Temperature Array
  {
    values2.splice(0, 1);
  }

  if(times.length > 6)//Delete the first value in the Time Array
  {
    times.splice(0, 1);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever a page changes in the browser, any webSockets or socket.io connections in that page are automatically closed by the browser.  In fact, there is nothing you can even do to prevent them from closing.

So, all you should have to do is to make sure that the **next** web page opens the correct socket for that next page.  The previous one will already be closed.  It is not clear at all from your code what "opening the humidity socket" means.

There are a number of ways you can open a socket and indicate to your server what type of data you want it to send.  You can send it a message indicating what type of data you want it to send you.  You can request a connection to a particular namespace (in socket.io) that your server will know about.  You can ask to join a particular room that will receive certain types of broadcasts.  That's all up to how you want to configure and design your clients and servers.  There is no preset way of doing that.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I think I have a general idea of what to do now.